# Warning: Undefined array key with my code php

Tags: php

[this my code error]

Warning: Undefined array key "state" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ASS1\Confirmation.php on line 16
Warning: Undefined array key "postal_code" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ASS1\Confirmation.php on line 17
Warning: Undefined array key "detail_address" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ASS1\Confirmation.php on line 18
Warning: Undefined array key "product_name" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ASS1\Confirmation.php on line 22
Warning: Undefined array key "product_price" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ASS1\Confirmation.php on line 23
Warning: Undefined array key "total_price" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ASS1\Confirmation.php on line 26

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Confirmation</title>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
</head>
<style >body {
            color: blue;
        }
</style>
<body>
    <h1>Confirmation</h1>

    <h2>User Information</h2>
    <p><b>Full Name:</b> <?php echo $_POST['full_name']; ?></p>
    <p><b>Phone Number:</b> <?php echo $_POST['phone_number']; ?></p>
    <p><b>State/Area:</b> <?php echo $_POST['state']; ?></p>
    <p><b>Postal Code:</b> <?php echo $_POST['postal_code']; ?></p>
    <p><b>Detail Address:</b> <?php echo $_POST['detail_address']; ?></p>
    <p><b>Notes:</b> <?php echo $_POST['notes']; ?></p>

    <h3>Product Details</h3>
    <p><b>Product Name:</b> <?php echo $_POST['product_name'];?></p>
    <p><b>Price:</b> <?php echo $_POST['product_price']; ?></p>

    <h3>Total Price</h3>
    <p><b>Total:</b> <?php echo $_POST['total_price']; ?></p>

    <h3>Payment Method</h3>
    <p><b>Selected Payment Method:</b> <?php echo $_POST['payment']; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, that happens when you use `$_POST['key']` when `key` doesn't exist...

Comment: You can use null coalescing operator to fix the error. Like below:

`<p><b>State/Area:</b> <?php echo $_POST['state'] ?? ''; ?></p>`

it means if the array key is found it will print a value otherwise empty.  You can learn more about the null coalescing operator [here](https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-null-coalescing-operator/)